# redirect word-press page with page values

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, urls, site-url

I am trying to redirect my wordpress page .
This code is working good.

```
<a href="'. get_permalink('dashboard') .'" class="wpum-profile-account-edit">'. __(' (Edit Account)', 'wpum') .'</a>
```

But I am trying to redirect with page value  " dashboard/?dashboard=myprofile" .But this code is not working

```
<a href="'. get_permalink('dashboard/?dashboard=myprofile') .'" class="wpum-profile-account-edit">'. __(' (Edit Account)', 'wpum') .'</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code and check`<a href="'. get_permalink('dashboard') .'?dashboard=myprofile" class="wpum-profile-account-edit">'. __(' (Edit Account)', 'wpum') .'</a>`. In get_permalink() function you can only pass the post ids or page titles to get the page url but you have added additional parameters with that so it was not getting the correct url. So I have edited the code to append the extra parameters after the function.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?